# Split a dataset by ranges of dates

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following dataset:

> ```
>        ID                 date            
>         A                 201806
>         B                 201809
>         C                 201901
>         D                 201905
>         E                 201906
>         F                 202002
>         G                 202003
>         H                 202004
> ```

Is there a way to split the dataset year by year from June to June of the next year?
Let say:

The new dataset 1 will be:

> ```
>        ID                 date            
>         A                 201806
>         B                 201809
>         C                 201901
>         D                 201905
> ```

from June (01) of 2018 to (31) May 2019

The new dataset 2 will be:

> ```
>        ID                 date   
>         E                 201906
>         F                 202002
>         G                 202003
>         H                 202004
> ```

from June (01) of 2019 to (30) April 2020

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it need to be flexible, as in, do you know how many datasets you want ahead of time or not? If you do a simple data step is enough, otherwise you need macro or a hash table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the posted results, I assume that 202006 should be 202004 in the last observations of your posted data.

It is rarely a good idea to split data like this, but you can do it like this

```
data have;
input ID $ date : yymmn6.;
format date yymmn6.;
datalines;
A 201806
B 201809
C 201901
D 201905
E 201906
F 202002
G 202003
H 202004
;

data temp;
   set have;
   from = intnx('year.6', date, 0, 'b');
   to   = intnx('year.6', date, 0, 'e');
run;

proc sort data = temp;
   by to;
run;

data _null_;

   if _N_ = 1 then do;                
      dcl hash h(dataset:"temp(obs=0)", multidata:'y', ordered : 'A'); 
      h.definekey('ID', 'date');                                                                        
      h.definedone();                                          
   end;

   do until(last.to);                                     
      set temp;                                             
      by to;
      h.add();                                                  
   end;

   h.output(dataset : cats('data_', _N_));                                   
   h.clear();     
 
run;
```

Comment: thank you very much PeterClemmensen and sorry for the mistake. I will edit soon